# Maximum value of certain element of all arrays in np array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with arrays within it:

```
array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

How am I able to find the maximum of all of the last elements of these inner arrays?  ie. for this case the return would be 9 `(max(3,6,9))`

I'm able to do this by converting to a Pandas dataframe first, but this is slowing down the program and I'm sure there's an easier way just using np.

Comment: Is it an array with arrays in it or a 2d array?  Also, I think you're missing a `[` before the 7 ...

Comment: conversion from list of lists to np.array using `d = np.array(l)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you meant to write

```
array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

then you can slice the last column with `A[:,-1]` and call `.max()`.

Comment: Does that have to be done iteratively? ie building a list from each slice and then applying .max()?

Comment: @McLeodx In terms of the Python code, no, it's a vectorized one-liner.

Comment: Nice working, thanks for that.  I think the comma is not necessary

Comment: You do need the comma in the brackets, because I believe you want to select *every* row and the last column. The indexing notation in numpy for 2d arrays is `[row, column]`. Without the comma, you're asking for the maximum value in the entire array except for the last row.

Comment: It seems to be working for me with [:-1].
`max = dataArray[:-1].max()` is finding the maximum value of all of the last elements in each row.  ie [1,2,3],[3,4,5] is returning 5